# Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /path/somthing.jar (Is a directory) when FileOutputStream object is created

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, io, create-directory

this is a really basic one, but it got me scratch my hear for 4 hours, now i'm giving up.
to give as much as possible information , i can say it's a java webapp project with zk 5.0.8 as frontend+spring+hibernate+maven  under ubuntu 11.04 with permission to the basedir set to 777.

tried the file upload everything seems to be ok and where i have confidence that my code is correct it's just not working.

here is the code

```
private boolean saveUploadledFile(Media uploadedMedia, String basedir) {

    String code = codeGenerator.generateContentCode(15);
    String FINAL_DIR_PATH = basedir + "/"+"Racing" + "/" + code;
    String FINAL_FILE_PATH = FINAL_DIR_PATH + "/" + uploadedMedia.getName();
    alert(FINAL_DIR_PATH);
    try {
        File finaldir = new File(FINAL_DIR_PATH);
        //apache commons
        FileUtils.forceMkdir(finaldir);
        alert("Size equals" + uploadedMedia.getByteData().length);
        fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(FINAL_DIR_PATH+"/"+addContentWindow1$txtName.getText()+".jar"));
          //apache commons
          IOUtils.copy(uploadedMedia.getStreamData(), fout);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(fout);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

new FileOutputStream always throws exceptions. so if i can't specify where i want to save how to save the files. any ideas? i intentionally output the size of the file to make sure there is a file. Can anyone shed some light? thanks for reading this

the actual exception is

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /joseph/mbcs/Games/Racing/20314/somthing.jar (is a directory)

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but isn't this part of your code faulty?

```
     if (!finaldir.exists()) {
        if (!finaldir.canWrite())
            finaldir.mkdirs(); // this creates no directory no error
         else
             alert("Cannot write to the directory" );
     }
```

If the directory doesn't exist, you check if you **can't** write there and then create it, otherwise you output an error. I think that `!` there is wrong.

Might be the reason for your problem but it just as well might not be.

Comment: Hi i corrected what you spotted but i guess it wasn't it.updated my post

Comment: Uh. I just realized that you never call `createNewFile()` on `finalfile`.

Comment: really ? is it really necessary here, i didn't find that method when i was comparing mine to various way on the net.but i guess there is obviously a problem creating the directory first.like i mentioned using a simple console project the directory gets created. don't even know what am missing here.thanks

Comment: updated based on your suggestion and am now getting lost.Still not working :(

Comment: Sorry...I have no clue how this exception relates to your code. According to the documentation the message states quite clearly that the file you attempt to write into, is actually a directory. I don't see how that could have happened based on your code.

Answer (score 1):

Leave out:

```
if(finalfile.canWrite()) {
```

as you just created the file and are writing to it.
You will get a misnamed FileNotFoundException (I think renamed in Java 7) when the OutputStream constructor failed in writing.

Another tip, general work like copying may be done using apache-commons (IOUtils, FileUtils),
i.e.:

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams;
Streams.copy(in, out, false);
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the tips. I think my problem is really on the fact that from the webapp i can't create a directory.So the problem happens actually before writing the outputstream. Maybe am wrong but the can write always returns false

Comment: By the way can you elaborate on your solution. i fail to see how to use it in my code, as am not familiar with that library.thanks

Comment: No one (else) can write to an already running FileOutputStream, hence File.canWrite returns false. Simply remove the test. Or do try { ... } catch (IOException e) { could not write }

Comment: DOne that already and directories are being created but i got another Exception all together.i don't really get why it's complaining of the file being a directory, thanks for replying